# Conexion a firebase fallida

Tags: java, firebase, servidor

Hola a todos mi problema es que quiero traer datos de una base de datos firebase con java de servidor pero no los trae me devuelve nulo.

Si me pueden ayudar porfavor se supone que tendria que devolver un json pero no devuelve nada. Segun la base de datos deberia devolver

```
{
    {"Lucho": "AAAAA"}, 
    {"Miguel": "BBBBBB"}
}
```

nombres
Lucas:
"Lucho"
Miguel:
"Miguel"

pero no me devuelve nada

```
hola porque no entra
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

esta es la parte que no funciona no entra al codigo.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
        System.out.println(ds.getKey());
        System.out.println(ds.getValue());
        System.out.println("hola");  
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError de) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
});
```

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo en donde declaras la variable ref ?

Comment: DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("/nombres");

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la ref es correcta y que llegas solo a un elemento, lo que importa es que la linea

```
System.out.println(ds.getValue());
```

en realidad debería ser algo como

```
System.out.println(ds.getValue(String.class));
```

O sea, al utilizar getValue debes incluir el tipo de dato que traemos.